# python: is this a good way to use the same function name for both classmethod and method?

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method

```
class A(object):

    @classmethod
    def print(cls):
        print 'A'

    def __print(self):
        print 'B'

    def __init__(self):
        self.print = self.__print


a = A()
a.print()
A.print()
```

I think it's too ugly, is there any other method to implement the same features? do not say combinemethod, because it creates an object every time.

Comment: What's the point of this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i try to use the same function name for both classmethod and method.

Comment: for example, we want to sharding the record by id. we use A.get_db_name(id=1) to calculate the db name for a new record. and we also can use a.get_db_name() to get the db name for an existed record.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to create a descriptor decorator like `classmethod` but that also passes the instance to the method:

```
from functools import partial
class descriptormethod(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return partial(self.fn, instance, owner)

class A(object):
    @descriptormethod
    def print_(self, cls):
        print 'A' if self is None else 'B'
```

Don't worry about the overhead of the descriptor or partial objects; it's no different from what happens when you call an instance or class method normally.